# Select all form button

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I was wondering how you can make a button on a form to select every row of the displayed datagridview?

The datagridview is just called `dgv` in my code.

Comment: @Plutonix I haven't tried anything yet, I was just wondering if it was possible to make button to do so. I have it now so I can go in and shift click all of the rows but I also want to add in a button and wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: You can, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the MSDN Page for the [DataGridView.SelectAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectall%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method it states.

> When the DataGridView is in column-selection mode and this method is called, each column's Selected property is set to true, and each row's Selected property is set to false.
>
> Conversely, when the DataGridView is in row-selection mode and this method is called, **each row's Selected property is set to true**, and each column's Selected property is set to false.

So something like this should work.

```
dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect 'Make sure this is enabled on your DataGridView

dgv.SelectAll() 'Put this in your click event
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. In your Button just loop through your datagridview.

```
        For each dr as Datagridviewrow in dgv.rows
        dr.selected = true
        Next
```

dr acts as your datagridview row.